# How to parse a JSON object with multiple values?

Tags: java, arrays, json, android-studio, object

I'm creating a trivia app and familiarizing myself with JSON, but i'm having trouble parsing a JSON object with multiple values to be able to assign each value to a Button.

I have a JSON that looks like this:

```
{
    "response_code": 0,
    "results": [{
            "question": "question one?",
            "correct_answer": "correct answer",
            "incorrect_answers": ["wrong1", "wrong2", "wrong3"]
        }, {
            "question": "question2",
            "correct_answer": "correct answer",
            "incorrect_answers": ["wrong1", "wrong2", "wrong3"]
        }
    ]
}
```

I am able to parse "question" and "correct_answer", but am not sure how to go about parsing the incorrect answers.

my Parser:

```
public class JsonParser
{

private URL urlin;
private static InputStream is = null;
private static JSONObject jObj = null;
private static JSONArray jArray = null;
private String jsonStr = " String to pass back";

public JsonParser()
{
    //empty constructor
}

public JSONObject getJSONfromURL (String url)
{
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
    try
    {
        urlin = new URL(url);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) urlin.openConnection();
        is = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line = null;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        urlConnection.disconnect();
        jsonStr = sb.toString();

    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            jObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
        }
        catch (JSONException je)
        {
            je.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return jObj;

}

}
```

How i'm parsing "question" and "correct_answer":

```
 myArray = myObj.getJSONArray("results");
 JSONObject tempObj = myArray.getJSONObject(0);
 question = tempObj.getString("question");
 A = tempObj.getString("correct_answer");
```

Comment: How are you parsing it? Like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android ?

Comment: tempObj.getJSONArray("incorrect_answers")

Comment: The link provided helps very much. Thank you

Comment: `{...}` is object, `[...]` is array. I formatted your JSON to make its structure more visible. This should let you see where to ask for string, object or array.